# access pixel values inside the detected object / c++

Tags: c++, opencv

If I could detect a circle by using canny edge detector, How can I have access to all values which are inside the circle?

```
void Canny(InputArray image, OutputArray edges, double threshold1, double threshold2, int apertureSize=3, bool L2gradient=false )
```

output of this function will give me the edge values which is detected by the edge detector, but what I want is all values inside the circle.

thanks in advance

------after editing.......

```
     Mat mask = Mat::zeros(canny_edge.rows, canny_edge.cols, CV_8UC1);
     Mat crop(main.rows, main.cols, CV_32FC1);
     main.copyTo( crop, mask );

     for(unsigned int y=0; y< height; y++)
          for(unsigned int x=0; x< width; x++)
              if(mask.at<unsigned char>(y,x) > 0)
               {

               }
```

Comment: in the edited version there are several problems:
1. I'm not sure what main and crop stand for, but you want to crop (or subimage) the mask too if that's the intention.
2. `mask` consists just of zeros there. The idea was to draw the object (filled with 255 values) on the mask image. So wherever the mask isn't zero, the pixel (of the mask) is inside the object and since mask and original image have same size, the pixel of the original image is inside the object too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a circle, as asked in the original question:

first you want to detect the circle (e.g. by using hough circle detection methods). If you've done that you have some kind of circle center and a radius. Have a look at http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html

After that you have to test whether a pixel is inside the circle. So one idea (and with openCV quite fast) is to **draw a filled circle on a mask image** and test for each pixel in the original image, whether the mask pixel at the same image coordinates is set (then the pixel is inside the object). This works for any other drawable object, draw it (filled) on the mask and test mask values.

Assuming you have a circle `center` and a `radius`, and the size of your original image is image_height x image_width, try this:

```
cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat::zeros(image_height,image_width, CV_8U);
cv::circle(mask, center, radius, cv::Scalar(255), -1);
for(unsigned int y=0; y<image_height; ++y)
  for(unsigned int x=0; x<image_width; ++x)
    if(mask.at<unsigned char>(y,x) > 0)
    {
      //pixel (x,y) in original image is within that circle so do whatever you want.
    }
```

though it will be more efficient if you limit the mask region (circle center +/- radius in both dimensions) instead of looping over the whole image ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for both answers. actually, the circle was just an example. the object which I am trying to detect it does not have a circle form or any specific shape. after applying a kind of edge detector like canny what should I do to have access to the all pixel values inside the detected edge?

Comment: I accept your answer (because I learned from that)but let me know what should I do in the case that the object does not have any specific shape.

Comment: I'm not sure if you have just all edges and don't know which edges build the concrete object, or if you know which of the edges form the object.
In both cases you can try to extract the **contour** of the object with some opencv methods (in the first case you'll have to sort out irrelevant contours later). If that is successful (mainly depending on the quality of your edge extraction) you can draw that contour filled on a mask an iterate over it just the same way as with a circle. You just have to replace `cv::circle()` with some contour drawing method.
An uploaded example image would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

For circles you should use the [Hough Circle Transform](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html). From it you will get the centres and radii of circles in your image. A given pixel is inside a particular circle if its distance from the center is less than the radius of the circle.

For a general shape, use [findCountours](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#void%20findContours%28InputOutputArray%20image,%20OutputArrayOfArrays%20contours,%20OutputArray%20hierarchy,%20int%20mode,%20int%20method,%20Point%20offset%29)  to get the outline of the shape, then you can use[pointPolygonTest](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=pointpolygontest#pointpolygontest) to determine wheether points are inside that shape. There is a [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/point_polygon_test/point_polygon_test.html)on it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. actually, the circle was just an example. the object which I am trying to detect it does not have a circle form or any specific shape. after applying a kind of edge detector like canny what should I do to have access to the all pixel values inside the detected edge?

Comment: I have added the answer to your new question to my answer.